# Replace values of a column in DF1 with corresponding values in DF2

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

---

I got two dataframes:

DF1: `Index(['Name', 'Timestamp'], dtype='object')` // 34424 rows × 2 columns

DF2: `Index(['Name', 'Description'], dtype='object')` // 103 rows × 2 columns

---

I want to replace the values in `DF1["Name"]` with the corresponding Description in `DF2["Description"]`

---

I tried the following code:

```
DF1['Name'] = DF2['Name'].map(DF1_index('Name')['Description'])
DF1
```

---

```
Error: "Description"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use merge for that:

```
df_merged = DF1.merge(DF2, on=["Name"], how="left")
```

If you want to keep the original index (DF2 has to have unique "Name" values though):

```
df_merged = DF1.reset_index().merge(DF2, on=["Name"], how="left").set_index("index")
```

Comment: Do you think merge function will work with dataframes with different sizes?

Comment: have you tested it? yes it definetly does.